# SQL - conditionally select a column if exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to select a column only if it exists in table, else it can be set to null.

Sample table below, lets say the `marks` col is not necessary be there, so need to be checked if it exists

**Table1**:

```
name marks
joe  10
john 11
mary 13
```

Query:

```
select
    name,
    marks if it exists else null as marks1 -- pseudo code
from 
    table1
```

What should go in line to select `marks` ?

Comment: How would you *not* know if `marks` is a column on table1?

Comment: You should **really** rethink the way you manage your database schema and migration. The fact that you don't know if a column exists or not could indicate that you are using the wrong process to create and update your tables in the database. Also: having a `marks1` table could also be a sign of a non-normalized design. You _could_achieve something like that with dynamic SQL but it would be **much** better to fix the way you manage your tables

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name agree on broader point - but this is not a question on schema & migration - real world data is messy :) and the context is not a application, it is some real world data coming in from a source I don't have control on - it may or may not all the expected columns - the question really was in this context if it possible to put some check for this.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - I expect `marks` to be there, but there is no guarantee that it would be there - so want to handle that situation.

Comment: Just issue an `ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN marks ( whatever );` if it's already there, let that statement fail -- no biggie.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: you don't even need the statement to fail: `alter table xxxx add column IF NOT EXISTS marks text;`

Comment: Evan approved. =) even betta.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Doesn't permit that. Your result set has two options:

1. Static inclusion
2. All from table or subquery  through column-expansion with `*` and `tbl.*`

Perhaps this will suit your needs, `SELECT * FROM table1;` You'll always get that column, if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
IF COL_LENGTH('your_table_name','column_name_you_want_to_select') IS NULL BEGIN 
 --This means columns does not exist or permission is denied
 END
 else 
 --Do whatever you want
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to achieve this in PostgreSQL using JSON. Consider the following SQL query:

```
SELECT c.relname, c.relkind, c.relispartition
FROM pg_class c
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','p') AND
      c.relnamespace=(SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname='public')
```

In PostgreSQL 10+, that will show you the names of all the tables in `public` schema, including whether they are partitioned and if so whether the table is the partitioned table or one of the partitions of it. However, if you try to run the same query on PostgreSQL 9.6 or earlier, it will fail since the `relispartition` column does not exist on the `pg_class` table prior to PostgreSQL 10.

An obvious solution would be to dynamically generate the SQL based on a condition, or have two different versions of the SQL. However, suppose you don't want to do that, you want to have a single query which works on both versions – in other words, you want to conditionally select the `relispartition` column if it exists.

The core SQL language does not have any facility to conditionally select a column, but it is achievable in PostgreSQL using the `row_to_json` function, as follows:

```
SELECT c.relname, c.relkind,
       (row_to_json(c)->>'relispartition')::boolean AS relispartition
FROM pg_class c
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','p') AND
      c.relnamespace=(SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname='public')
```

If you try running that, you will find on PostgreSQL 10+ the `relispartition` column is returned as `true`/`false`, whereas in pre-10 versions it is `NULL`. You could make it return `false` instead of `NULL` in pre-10 versions by doing `COALESCE((row_to_json(c)->>'relispartition')::boolean,false)`.

What this is doing, is `row_to_json(c)` turns all the data of the row into JSON. Next, `->>'relispartition'` selects the value of the `relispartition` JSON object key as text, which will be the same as the value of the `relispartition` column; if there is no such key in the JSON, the result of that will be `NULL`. Then, `::boolean` converts the string value `true`/`false` back into a PostgreSQL boolean value. (If your column is of some other type, use the appropriate cast for the type of your column.)

(Obviously this approach will not work in Postgres versions which are too old to have the necessary JSON support – I have tested it works in Postgres 9.4; while I haven't tested it in Postgres 9.3, it probably works there. However, I would not expect it to work in 9.2 or earlier – the `->>` operator was added in 9.3, and the JSON type and `row_to_json` function was added in 9.2. However, I expect few people will need to support those old unsupported versions–9.3 was released in 2013, and 9.2 supported ended in 2017.)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT 1
           FROM information_schema.columns 
           WHERE table_name='your_table' and column_name='your_column') THEN
   SELECT your_column as 'some_column'
ELSE
   SELECT NULL as 'some_column'
END IF
```

Comment: @EvanCarroll PostgreSQL doesn't support `EXISTS()`?

Comment: Yes, in `plpgsql`. That's a procedural language and it's one of many that PostgreSQL supports. However that's not SQL. You can't just run a snippet that is otherwise valid in the procedural language.

Comment: you may replace it with `count`

Answer (score 0):

Replying to an old question yet again but here's my hacky solution to this problem since I don't know how to write SQL functions... yet! `%I` formats the string as an identifier, and if there is no such table the return value is NULL and the alias is used!

```
SELECT (SELECT format('%I', 'my_column')
 AS my_column_alias
 FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name='my_table'
 AND column_name='my_column') 
FROM source_table
```

Hope this helps everybody out there =)

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns the string `my_column` if that column exists, and `NULL` otherwise. But the question was asking to return, not the name of the column if it exists, but rather its value for each row.